# EasyPHP 12.1 Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, environment-variables

This is one of the errors that I get when I launch `php` command in my Windows prompt.[image]

I've installed the environment through EasyPHP 12.1 installer. This is a minor problem, since i can use without any problem the full LAMP stack. 
I noticed the problem just because ApiGen needs `mbstring` to create documentation (picture above actually is related to bz2 library, but nothing changes for other missing library). Last path in the warning sounds strange since don't exist nothing PHP related in my LaTex distribution. Any suggest about the problem???

Answer (score 1):

Time ago I have same problem. This work for me.

http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.cz/2011/02/solving-php-startup-unable-to-load.html